# Accessible YouTube client

Tags: android, youtube, accessibility

I am needing a YouTube client for Android that has been designed with accessibility in mind, the official YouTube client is terrible in this regard. The issues my grandfather is finding are as follows:

- The controls for video playback disappear far too quickly. They are only visible for maybe 2-3 seconds or so before being hidden, far too quick for an older person to process the screen.
- The controls for full screen video and the timeline are far too small.
- The UI is too cluttered, ideally if he is on a page watching a video, that is all that should be shown. No need for suggested videos, comments etc.

The YouTubeKids app would appear perfect if it were not themed for kids, which is a little demeaning for an adult to be using. And secondly, the content that he wants to watch on YouTube will not play through the YouTube Kids app.

Comment: Try [NewPipe](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.schabi.newpipe&fdpage=38)

Comment: That looks rather promising, could you please post this as an answer.